# require / include no spaces, line break

Tags: php

sorry for my english but I'm Italian and I'm not very practical, I still hope you manage to understand me. 
So, I was recently working with php and wondered if it was possible, by calling the function require or include, remove all spaces and line breaks. I would be fine in some other way, without using the include or require function, as long as you get to the end result.

I have the following CSS file:

```
/* GENERAL */
body { ... }
a { ... }
etc.
```

and I want it, including it displays it in this way:

```
/*GENERAL*/body{ ... }a{ ... }etc.
```

And this will I include in a PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

You want to google for a css minifier and may find e.g. [this](https://code.google.com/p/cssmin/). PHP does not provide functionality of this kind by default. Especially not within a simple include/require.